# How to convert special characters to hex? ( in Android )

Tags: android, hex, special-characters

> **Convert some special characters into hex value.**
>
> For example :
>
> Hex value of "ㅂ" is "e3 85 82"
>
> Hex value of "ㅈ", "ㄷ", and "ㄱ" are "e3 85 88", "e3 84 b7", and  "e3 84 b1" respectively.

I tried below method but it works only for ";", "#" etc

> **Integer.toHexString("ㅂ")** , gives **"3142"** value. But correct hex value should be "e3 85 82".
>
> [String to Hex](http://chxo.com/scripts/hex2string.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer encoding is in UNICODE(hex) and you need to convert it into UTF8(hex)

Convert String to hex.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String chr = "ㅂ";
    System.out.print(toHex(chr));
}
//String to hex
public static String toHex(String arg) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    //Change encoding according to your need 
    return String.format("%04x", new BigInteger(1, arg.getBytes("UTF8")));
}
```

Output:- e38582

Comment: String.format("%04x", 'ㅂ') also gives the same result 3142, but the correct hex value is **e3 85 82**.

Comment: I converted it into Unicode(hex) but you need UTF8(hex).

Edited the answer have a look on it.

Comment: **String.format("%x", new BigInteger(1, "ㅂ".getBytes("UTF8"))** It works fine. Thanks

Comment: How to get back the original String. See this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25138514/how-to-convert-hex-value-to-special-char-in-unicode